# "Converse" Schur's lemma

Tags: representation-theory

For representations over an algebraically closed field one can formulate Schur's lemma in the following form:

> Every endomorphism of irreducible representation is of the form $\lambda\cdot id$

I wonder, if the converse is true, i.e if all endomorphisms of representation are scalar then it is irreducible. It's easy to see that such representation must be indecomposable, but what about irreducibility?(case of non-algebraically closed field is also interesting)

Comment: Searching "converse of Schur's lemma" immediately turns up two or three duplicates. Please use the search feature and/or similar questions feature before asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true. Consider for example the category ${\mathscr A}$ of representations of the $A_2$-quiver $\bullet\to\bullet$ over an arbitrary field ${\mathbb k}$; that is, objects in ${\mathscr A}$ are homomorphisms of ${\mathbb k}$-vector spaces $V\to W$ and morphisms in ${\mathscr A}$ are commutative squares. It is equivalent to the category of modules over the $3$-dimensional algebra $\scriptsize\begin{pmatrix}\ast & \ast\\ 0 & \ast\end{pmatrix}$, the path algebra over ${\mathbb k}$ of $\bullet\to\bullet$.

In ${\mathscr A}$ consider the projective module $P := {\mathbb k}\xrightarrow{1}{\mathbb k}\ $: It is not simple since $0\to {\mathbb k}$ is a non-trivial submodule, however $\text{Hom}_{\mathscr A}(P,V\to W)\cong V$, so in particular $\text{dim}_{\mathbb k}\ \text{End}_{\mathscr A}(P)=1$.